# HttpPost how to receive parameters c#

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, http-post

I have a method on web service and I need to receive parameters with [HttpPost].
I am new at this, and I really don't know how.
I need to receive the following:

**** long requestId, string text, byte[] audio, short languageId****

```
    public void AddAnswer (long requestId, string text, byte[] audio, short languageId) 
    {
        string userIdWhoAnswers = (User as TokenPrincipal).userId.ToString();

        long userId = Convert.ToInt64(userIdWhoAnswers);

        using (var context = new WordsEntities())
        {
            Answers answer = new Answers();
            answer.requestId = requestId;
            answer.userId = 10;
            answer.text = text;

            answer.audioExtension = audio;
            DateTime datee = DateTime.Now;
            answer.timePosted = datee;
            answer.languageId = languageId;

            context.Answers.Add(answer);
            context.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
```

This is my method but with HttpGet, I need to convert it to HttpPost.
Can someone please help me?

Answer (score 1):

Looking your code I think you are sending the information using the body and not the url (in fact you are trying to send a byte array that usually isn't compatible with the query string).

For this reason you have to use the [FromBody](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.http.frombodyattribute%28v=vs.118%29.aspx) attribute near to the parameter name

```
public void AddAnswer ([FromBody] long requestId, [FromBody] string text, [FromBody] byte[] audio, [FromBody] short languageId)
```

moreover I think that the byte[] doesn't work. Probably you have to work with multipart

Comment: it worked when i sent parameters using the url..
now i just need to convert this to httppost and take parameters with json..

Answer (score 0):

you can refer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30941827/how-to-retrieve-httppost-parameters-in-c-sharp) and specially [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/parameter-binding-in-aspnet-web-api)

TLDR; FromBody accepts just one parameter; try passing a JSON string with all required inputs in a single parameter to your HttpPost.